# Replacing LED bulb on a 1.2 V battery-operated solar garden light

Tags: led

First, I have read some interesting information about 1.2 V battery-operated solar lights on this site. I want to replace the LED bulb associated with a solar puck that I own. It has a 1.2 V rechargeable battery. The battery voltage at the led is 1.2 V using digital multimeter. It charges during the day at 1.89 V using the solar panel associated with it. An old oscilloscope reflects a similar wave form that I have reviewed on your site with another enthusiast. I don't know at what frequency the circuit pulses for the LED but the wave form projects about 2.5 volts.

I am an enthusiast, love to mess around with this stuff. Can these bulbs be purchased for replacement and if so does anyone know where I can find them or how to obtain some LED bulbs for these? I do not know whether the driver in this device is constant current or constant voltage. Else may I need to know in order to purchase a correct led bulb if they can be had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEDs are now commodity products that you can buy from any electrical component retailer.  They can be very cheap (per LED) if bought in bulk.  Solar lamps typically use standard LED types.

The circuits in these solar lamps aren't constant voltage or current.  It takes more than 1.2V to light an LED.  So the circuit uses an oscillator and an inductor to provide brief pulses of higher voltage to run the LED.